# Having an issue changing screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm having an issue changing screen.I don't know why the Navigaotr.push command doesn't working.
Everything other than that works fine such as getting the long,alt etc..
Everything other than that works fine such as getting the long,alt etc..

Utility class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

loading_Screen Class:

```
import 'package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/networking.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'location_screen.dart';

const apiKey = '65c8f19a8cd46bb90e565af0a07cbd61';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  @override
  void iniState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocationData();
  }

  void getLocationData() async {
    Location location = new Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    latitude = location.latitude;
    longitude = location.longitude;
    print('got here');
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&$longitude=139&appid=$apiKey');
    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return LocationScreen();
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

location_screen
[image]

after changing the location of the print after the await

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(11532): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e4051e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e403400)

info: Method doesn't override an inherited method. (override_on_non_overriding_method at [clima] lib\screens\loading_screen.dart:21)
info: The value of the local variable 'weatherData' isn't used. (unused_local_variable at [clima] lib\screens\loading_screen.dart:36)
info: Avoid empty statements. (empty_statements at [clima] lib\services\networking.dart:16)
info: Dead code. (dead_code at [clima] lib\services\networking.dart:16)
```

Comment: A better approach would be to have your LocationScreen as your main Home Screen, and call your getLocationData method in the LocationScreen's initState method, and just set a flag with setState that determines whether the build method returns a CircularProgressIndicator widget or the data that has been loaded. Otherwise when the user hits 'back' they will be taken back to the loading screen by default, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: ok,but anyway I would like to understand why it's not working..

Comment: how is it not working? what does the location screen class look like? you will need to provide more details if you want a specific answer.

Comment: @Kris just did while editing

Comment: Put the `print('got here')` after the `await networkHelper.getData();` .

Comment: @ArashMohammadi?????

Comment: @NivTzemach I just want to know if it gets there :)

Comment: @ArashMohammadi just did and i got some warnings

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are receiving the error:

> info: Method doesn't override an inherited method. (override_on_non_overriding_method at [clima] lib\screens\loading_screen.dart:21)

is that you created an iniState() function instead of an initState() function.